# The log doesn't match the actual HTML on the page

Tags: javascript

[ so i cant post images on here yet. So ill try my best to explain. im confused because when i click the randomize button it randomizes the html elements and it also appends it properly on the web, but when i actually take a closer look into the console, i see that the names array doesnt match the index to those posted on the html. maybe there is nothing wrong and im just lacking something about the concept applied. Thank you in advance]

```js
`use strict`;

// const plcHolder = document.querySelector("#placheholder");
const btnAdd = document.querySelector(".add-btn");
const btnRan = document.querySelector(".ran-btn");
const btnDeleteAll = document.getElementById("delete");
const namesBtn = document.querySelector(".add-name");
let list = [];
let names = [];
// console.log(list);
console.log(names);
//ADD TODOS FUNCTION///////////

const addList = function () {
  var plcHolder = document.getElementById("placeholder").value;

  if (plcHolder === "") {
    alert(`Please type a todo`);
  } else {
    var getParent = document.querySelector(".ul-list-container");
    var listTodo = document.createElement("li");
    createAnchor = plcHolder;
    // console.log(plcHolder);
    listTodo.className = "text list-todos flexbox-space";

    var createAnchor = document.createElement("a");
    var linkText = document.createTextNode(plcHolder);
    createAnchor.className = "check";
    createAnchor.href = "#";
    list.push(plcHolder);
    getParent.appendChild(listTodo);

    listTodo.appendChild(createAnchor);
    createAnchor.appendChild(linkText);
    console.log(list);
    document.getElementById("placeholder").value = "";
  }
};
btnAdd.addEventListener(`click`, addList);
////// DELETEALL FUNCTION

const deleteAll = function () {
  var getParent = document.querySelector(".ul-list-container");
  // var listTodo = document.createElement("li");
  if (list.length > 0) {
    list.length = [];
    while (getParent.firstChild) {
      getParent.removeChild(getParent.firstChild);
    }
  }
};
btnDeleteAll.addEventListener(`click`, deleteAll);

/// DELETE Single //

const addNameBtn = function () {
  var namePlcHolder = document.querySelector(`.name-placeholder`).value;

  if (namePlcHolder === "") {
    console.log(alert(`Please type a name`));
  } else {
    const getUlNames = document.querySelector(`.names`);
    const createDiv = document.createElement("div");
    createDiv.className = "name-container";
    const createLiName = document.createElement(`li`);
    createLiName.className = "text list-todos";
    document.getElementById(`name-holder`).value = "";

    const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 490 500");
    svg.setAttribute("class", "bin");

    const path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    path.setAttribute(
      "d",
      "M135.2 17.7L128 32H32C14.3 32 0 46.3 0 64S14.3 96 32 96H416c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32H320l-7.2-14.3C307.4 6.8 296.3 0 284.2 0H163.8c-12.1 0-23.2 6.8-28.6 17.7zM416 128H32L53.2 467c1.6 25.3 22.6 45 47.9 45H346.9c25.3 0 46.3-19.7 47.9-45L416 128z"
    );
    svg.appendChild(path);

    // createElem.src =
    const createDelete = document.createElement(`button`);
    // createDelete.innerHTML = "a";
    createDelete.id = "bin-btn";
    getUlNames.appendChild(createDiv);
    createDiv.appendChild(createDelete);
    createDelete.appendChild(svg);
    createLiName.textContent = namePlcHolder;
    names.push(namePlcHolder);
    var childre = getUlNames.appendChild(createLiName);
    // console.log(createLiName, names); // turn this one to see the whole line created with text content
    createDiv.appendChild(childre);

    // var getBin = document.getElementsByClassName("bin-btn");

    createDelete.addEventListener("click", function () {
      createDiv.remove();
      // const index = names.indexOf(names);
    });
  }
};

const nameEnter = document.querySelector(".name-placeholder");
const getListHolder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

///REPEATED CODE
// getListHolder.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
//   if (e.key === "Enter") {
//     e.preventDefault();
//     addList();
//   }
// });
// nameEnter.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
//   if (e.key === "Enter") {
//     e.preventDefault();
//     addNameBtn();
//   }
// });

////SIMPLIFIED CODE
const enter = function (e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target === getListHolder) {
      addList();
    } else if (e.target === nameEnter) {
      addNameBtn();
    }
  }
};

nameEnter.addEventListener("keypress", enter);
getListHolder.addEventListener("keypress", enter);

const random = function () {
  const ulList = document.getElementById("names-list");
  var temp;

  for (var i = names.length; i > 0; i--) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    console.log(randomNumber);
    if (names[randomNumber] !== undefined) {
      temp = names[randomNumber];
      const t = (names[randomNumber] = names[i - 1]);
      console.log(t);
      names[i - 1] = temp;

      for (var i = ulList.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        var namePositions = ulList.appendChild(
          ulList.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * i)]
        );
      }
      // if (ulList.children === names[i]) {
      //   random();
      // }
    }
  }
  console.log(names);
  return names;
};
btnRan.addEventListener("click", random);

namesBtn.addEventListener("click", addNameBtn);

// checked TOdo List //

// const checkedList = document.querySelector(".check");

// checkedList.addEventListener("click", function () {
//   if (checkedList.className !== checked) {
//     checkedList.className = "checked";
//   } else checkedList.toggle("checked");
// });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(237, 250, 250);
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 570px;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
p {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#text {
  font-size: 29px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.text {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.btn {
  margin: 1px 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: aliceblue;
  background-color: rgba(122, 200, 236, 0.839);
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.add-name {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.ul-list-container {
  color: aliceblue;

  text-decoration: underline;
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}

#placeholder {
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.main-container {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}
.list-todos {
  padding: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.list-flex {
}
.flexbox-space {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(125, 204, 241, 0.878);
}
.flex-container {
  padding-top: 5px;

  background-color: rgba(116, 156, 156, 0.157);

  border-radius: 8px;

  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: 230px auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(116, 108, 108, 0.434);
}

.name-list {
  display: flex;

  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  gap: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.name-label {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.name-placeholder {
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 3px;
}

/* Single Name Delete btn */
.name-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.single-delete {
  font-size: 5px;
}

/* TRASHH ICON */
.bin {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
#bin-btn {
  height: 30px;

  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(116, 156, 156, 0.157);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
}
#bin-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#bin-btn:active {
  background-color: rgba(197, 213, 213, 0.403);
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-color: red;
}
.right-flexbox {
  margin-left: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 250px;
}
.check {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: aliceblue;
}
.check:hover {
  color: red;
}
.check:visited {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <link>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Todo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  
      
  </head>
  <body>
      
      <div class="main-container" >
          <form class="form">
              <label class="text " id="text" type="text">Your List</label>
              <input
              type="text"
             
              id="placeholder"
              placeholder=" Type your chores here..">
            </input>
            <button type="button" class="btn add-btn">Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn ran-btn">Randomize</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn del-btn" id="delete">Delete All</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- <form class="name-list"><label class="name-label">Names</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder=" Type names.." class="name-placeholder">
        <button type="button" class="btn add-name">Add</button>
    </form> -->
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="left-flexbox ">
        <form class="name-list"><label class="name-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder=" Type names.." class="name-placeholder" id="name-holder">
            <button type="button" class="btn add-name">Add</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="names" id="names-list">
          
            <!-- <li class="text list-todos">Judi   </li>
            -->
        </ul>
    </div>
     <div class="right-flexbox">
          <div class="list-title">

            <p>Your List</p>
          </div>
        
      <div class="list-flex">
        <ul id='list-container'class="ul-list-container">
            <!-- <li class="text list-todos">shopping   </li> -->
           
        </ul>
      </div>
    <!-- <div>
        <ul class="ul-list-names">
            <li class="text list-names">: Leo</li>
        </ul>
    </div> -->
     </div>
</div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[ so i cant post images on here yet. So ill try my best to explain. im confused because when i click the randomize button it randomizes the html elements and it also appends it properly on the web, but when i actually take a closer look into the console, i see that the names array doesnt match the index to those posted on the html. maybe there is nothing wrong and im just lacking something about the concept applied. Thank you in advance]

```
const random = function () {
  const ulList = document.getElementById("names-list");
  var temp;

  for (var i = names.length; i > 0; i--) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    console.log(randomNumber);
    if (names[randomNumber] !== undefined) {
      temp = names[randomNumber];
      const t = (names[randomNumber] = names[i - 1]);
      console.log(t);
      names[i - 1] = temp;

      for (var i = ulList.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        var namePositions = ulList.appendChild(
          ulList.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * i)]
        );
      }
      // if (ulList.children === names[i]) {
      //   random();
      // }
    }
  }
  console.log(names);
  return names;
};
btnRan.addEventListener("click", random);
```

Comment: You're randomising the list of children of the <ul> independently of the array. Do either of the two and then log that if you want them to be the same.

Comment: Where is the array names defined? Where is btnRan element selected? Your code is not working, please post the working version and the HTML code.

Comment: i added the working code. sorry for the messineess im new here : )